# I'm using a function in JS that changes the color to red and then to green onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm using a function in JS that changes the color to red and then to green onclick. When I click the div, it changes to red, but when I click it again, it stays red, when it's supposed to change back to green. I looked over my code multiple times, but I can't figure out how to fix my problem.

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="c" onclick="func()"></div>

<style>
#c{
background:#00ff00;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
</style>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById('c');
function func(){
if(c.style.background = "#00ff00"){
c.style.background = "#ff0000";
}
else if(c.style.background = "#ff0000"){
c.style.background = "#00ff00";
}
}
</script>

</body>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The background-style can not be retrieved using `.style.background` here (you can only do that for inline styles). If you want to retrieve a style, use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). You can make your life easier using a css-class and `.classList.toggle`.

Furthermore: it's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. Assign handlers within your code.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", toggleColor);

function toggleColor(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "c") {
    evt.target.classList.toggle("red");
  }
}
```

```css
#c {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#c.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="c"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script tag, in the if statement, when you are comparing two things, use `===` or `==`. You cannot use `=` since it is an assignment operator and does not return true or false.

This is how the function should be written.

```
<script>
var c = document.getElementById('c');
function func(){
if(c.style.background === "#00ff00"){
c.style.background = "#ff0000";
}
else if(c.style.background === "#ff0000"){
c.style.background = "#00ff00";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to toggle between two different styles for the same element is by using classes. It looks neat and also helps you to change multiple attributes in a single place rather than writing multiple lines of code for doing a similar thing. So, try this:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="c" class="green" onclick="func()"></div>

<style>
#c{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
</style>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var func = function(){
if(c.classList.contains('green')){
  c.classList.remove('green');
  c.classList.add('red');
} else if(c.classList.contains('red')) {
  c.classList.remove('red');
  c.classList.add('green');
}
};
</script>

</body>
```

Here's the jsfiddle link for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/khushboo097/qf9t68zd/2

Answer (score -1):

try this`

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="c" onclick="func()"></div>

<style>
#c{
background:#00ff00;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
</style>

<script>
var x = 0;
var c = document.getElementById('c');
function func(){
if(!x){
c.style.background = "#ff0000";
x = 1;
}
else{
c.style.background = "#00ff00";
x = 0;
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, but could you explain why the x variable makes such a difference? I'm relatively new to javascript.

Comment: Just using an extra variable is the most simplest way.